# How to install only javadoc?

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk

I installed **java** downloading the relative file from the Oracle site, and following the manual guide I found on http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org . I have it and it works.

Now I'm trying using `javadoc` with the following command:

```
$ javadoc -version -private -d /tmp/Docs -sourcepath src -subpackages it
```

But I receive this error message:

```
The program 'javadoc' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * gcj-5-jdk
 * openjdk-8-jdk-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jdk
 * gcj-4.9-jdk
 * openjdk-9-jdk-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

As I **already installed java**, how should I proceed to get **javadoc** too? I'm afraid any of the packages suggested could result in some problems as I already have a jdk.

**Note:** I would prefer not to use openjdk.

Comment: Java isn't JDK. For `javadoc`, you need a JDK installed. From your question, you don't already have a JDK installed.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get javadocs is to install a JRE or a JDK. If you picked one that did not have javadoc you will need to install one that does.

No way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way is to install **javadoc** via npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/javadoc

```
$ npm install -s javadoc
+ javadoc@1.0.6
added 235 packages from 100 contributors and audited 81 packages in 8.795s
found 0 vulnerabilities

$ javadoc --version
javadoc 12.0.1
```

Comment: Why use npm when apt is the native platform installer?

Answer (score 0):

For me `apt install openjdk-16-jdk-headless` worked for  # version 16.0.1+9-1~20.04